# Dynamically add values to textarea from input field by button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input form containing 4 input fields. Two are drop-down and 2 are text fields. When user will Fill up the fields and click + button beside it then in the bellow text area all the values will be copied and the 4 input fields will be cleared.

the four input fields are:

```
   <select class="small-field"  name="type" id="type" >
         <option>Laptop</option>
         <option>Desktop</option>
         <option>Printer</option>
   </select>
   <select class="small-field"  name="brand" id="model" >
        <option>HP</option>
        <option>Dell</option>
        <option>Advantech</option>
   </select>
   <input class="small-field" type="text" id="model" name="model" placeholder="model">
   <input type="text" id="qty" name="quantity" placeholder="qty." style="width: 50px">
   <input type="button"  id="addthis" style="width: 30px" value="+" class="button">
```

and the text-area is as follows-

```
<textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>
```

and the script i have written for this is

```
$(function() {                                    
    $("#addthis").onclick(function('#type') {                
        $('#details').val(this.value);                       
    });
    $("#addthis").onclick(function('#brand') {                
        $('#details').val(this.value);                       
    });
    $("#addthis").onclick(function('#model') {                
        $('#details').val(this.value);                       
    });
    $("#addthis").onclick(function('#qty') {                
        $('#details').val(this.value);                       
    });
});
```

the final output in the textarea will be like follows-

```
Type: Laptop , Brand: HP, Model: CQ4587, Qty: 5
Type: Laptop , Brand: Dell, Model: CQ4587, Qty: 3
Type: Laptop , Brand: HP, Model: CQ4587, Qty: 2
Type: Desktop , Brand: HP, Model: CQ4587, Qty: 7
```

Comment: sorry. spelling mistake.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your code, changing some ids and change the script. You had some elements with the same id.

```
<select class="small-field"  name="type" id="type" >
  <option>Laptop</option>
  <option>Desktop</option>
  <option>Printer</option>
</select>
<select class="small-field"  name="brand" id="model" >
  <option>HP</option>
  <option>Dell</option>
  <option>Advantech</option>
</select>
<input class="small-field" type="text" id="model_value" name="model" placeholder="model">
<input type="text" id="qty" name="quantity" placeholder="qty." style="width: 50px">
<input type="button"  id="addthis" style="width: 30px" value="+" class="button">
<textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>
```

In the script I've got the value of each input and display into the textarea. And the script would be

```
<script>
$("#addthis").click(function(){
  $("#details").val(
     $("#details").val() +
     "Type: "+$("#type").val() + 
      " , Brand: "+$("#model").val() +
      ", Model: "+$("#model_value").val() +
      ", Qty: "+$("#qty").val() +"\n"
  );
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwgnx2sw/1/

I hope it helps.

Comment: Partially its is correct. But i when another value will be added it will concate with the previous value. Can you please edit it like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the values are concatenated (and that all previously-entered values are retained) I've amended your HTML to the following (to group the relevant items together, using a `<fieldset>`, and removed the `id` properties of the various children for validation purposes):

```
<fieldset class="details">
  <select class="small-field" name="type">
    <option>Laptop</option>
    <option>Desktop</option>
    <option>Printer</option>
  </select>
  <select class="small-field" name="brand">
    <option>HP</option>
    <option>Dell</option>
    <option>Advantech</option>
  </select>
  <input class="small-field" type="text" name="model" placeholder="model">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="qty." style="width: 50px">
</fieldset>
<input type="button" style="width: 30px" value="+" class="button">
<textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>
```

And the jQuery:

```
// binding the click event-handler to the '#addthis' element:
$('#addthis').on('click', function() {
  // creating a reference to all <fieldset class="details"> elements:
  var fieldsets = $('fieldset.details'),
    // getting the last of those <fieldset> elements:
    last = fieldsets.last();

  // hiding the last one,
  last.hide()
      // cloning it:
     .clone()
     // looking to its child-elements' value property:
     .children().prop('value', function(i, v) {
        // setting the value to the assigned default-value:
        return this.defaultValue;
  })
    // moving back to the previous selection, the cloned-<fieldset>:
    .end()
    // inserting the clone before the button:
    .insertBefore(this)
    // showing the cloned <fieldset>:
    .show();

  // setting the value of the #details element:
  $('#details').val(function() {
    // creating a map of:
    return fieldsets.map(function() {
      // ...a map of the children of each of the <fieldset> elements' children:
      return $(this).children().map(function() {
        // a string of the name, ': ' and values:
        return this.name + ': ' + this.value;
      // joining that together into an array, joined by ', ':
      }).get().join(', ');
    // joining those arrays together with newlines:
    }).get().join('\n');
  });
});
```

```js
$('#addthis').on('click', function() {
  var fieldsets = $('fieldset.details'),
    last = fieldsets.last();
  last.hide().clone().children().prop('value', function(i, v) {
    return this.defaultValue;
  }).end().insertBefore(this).show();
  $('#details').val(function() {
    return fieldsets.map(function() {
      return $(this).children().map(function() {
        return this.name + ': ' + this.value;
      }).get().join(', ');
    }).get().join('\n');
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="details">
  <select class="small-field" name="type">
    <option>Laptop</option>
    <option>Desktop</option>
    <option>Printer</option>
  </select>
  <select class="small-field" name="brand">
    <option>HP</option>
    <option>Dell</option>
    <option>Advantech</option>
  </select>
  <input class="small-field" type="text" name="model" placeholder="model">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="qty." style="width: 50px">
</fieldset>
<input type="button" id="addthis" style="width: 30px" value="+" class="button">
<textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
  - [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).